# MOSS Search Crawler Impact Rules

Tags: sharepoint

I am kind of confused on the crawler impact rules settings. In the SharePoint docs it is mensioned that impact rules are farm-wide and apply to all content sources. What is the point of entring the site name then? What would be an example? Would it be an URL?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The example would be a URL. Say you are crawling http://intranet/heavilyusedsite you could limit the requests to that site by adding the url.

The url is there because site collections and separate sites may be added using managed paths. E.g. http://intranet/sites/admin vs http://intranet/sites/hr may be separate site collections or even web applications, requiring different crawling limitations.